# Vim requires .vimrc to be sourced every time when running in tmux

Tags: linux, vim, tmux, vim-plugin

I have made several changes to my `.vimrc` file, which includes several [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) plugins, some syntax/coloring options and some key mappings.

Whenever I open a new Vim session however, not all of these are being applied (most notably coloring and syntax highlighting). If I run `:so ~/.vimrc` the file gets sourced and the changes apply immediately. Obiously I don't want to have to do this every time I start vim.

Why are these changes not being applied automatically? (This is after a complete restart and new terminal/vim session).

**Update**
I've discovered this is related to [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/). When I run `vim` straight from terminal, `.vimrc` is applied as expected. If I run `vim` from inside a `tmux` session, then I have to manually source the file every time.

Any ideas how to solve this?

`~/.vimrc` contents:

```
" PLUGINS - see vim-plug
call plug#begin()
 Plug 'crusoexia/vim-monokai'
 Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
 Plug 'crusoexia/vim-javascript-lib'
call plug#end()

" Enable Monokai colors
syntax on
colorscheme monokai
set t_Co=256

" Easy tab movement with keys 1|2
nmap 1 :tabp <enter>
nmap 2 :tabn <enter>

" Line Numbers
set number

" 2 space tabs
set tabstop=8 softtabstop=2 expandtab shiftwidth=2 smarttab
```

Comment: see if this helps: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file/2004#2004

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't help - if I disable loading of `.vimrc` then I can't diagnose the problem, and if I disable the plugins/settings in `.vimrc` then I can't tell whether it was sourced!

Comment: Please show us your `vimrc`.

Comment: Thanks, see updated post.

Comment: After loading a session, do you see your `.vimrc` in `:scriptnames` output; i.e. is it sourced at all (but ineffectively)?

Comment: Thanks, `~/.vimrc` is included in the `:scriptnames` output.

Comment: The problem is related to tmux - please see update in original post.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's the same Vim outside of tmux and in tmux?

Comment: Yes, in both cases, `which vim` returns `/usr/bin/vim`

Comment: can you try typing :messages after you launch vim the first time? Maybe something is not run correctly at startup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, tmux was overriding the `TERM` value until `.vimrc` was sourced.

Running `echo $TERM` in a regular shell gave `xterm-256color`, whereas running it in tmux gave `screen`.

The solution was to explicitly export the desired `TERM` value:

`export TERM="xterm-256color"`

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but where should I put the line `export TERM...`? Also, it is recommended not to change TERM: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ

Comment: @Yankee `export TERM...` is a generic command that sets the `TERM` environment variable. Where you put it depends on your setup, but likely options are `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` or `~/.zshrc` etc